# how to do an automatic adding input field according to the number of value inputted by user?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Can i ask how to automatically add input field according to the number of  inputted value of the user?.. it should be adding during the filling out of the form not after it is submitted
Example:  number of iput field: 2

## 1

## 2

Comment: Show us some code you've already tried, and we can help you get the rest of the way there. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Ok i will, im sorry its my first time here..

Answer (score 0):

**try this jquery for dynamic insert textbox depend upon user input**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="number_of_textbox">
<div id="append"></div>
<button id="btn">Add</button>
<script>
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
    var i=1;
 var number_of = $('#number_of_textbox').val();
 for(i;i<=number_of;i++)
 {
    $('#append').append('<input type="text" name="text'+i+'" id="text'+i+'" placeholder="textbox '+i+'"> ');
 }
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "$('#append').empty();" to ensure not to add duplicate input controls when number of input fields are changed.